# Parsing with Gson

Tags: android, gson

I am try to fetch data through Gson. But nothing fetched, I don't get response.

Here is the JSON data:

```
{
    "sw_name": "Comcept (Pvt) Ltd",
    "sw_id": 2,
    "sw_locations": "Islamabad",
    "sw_address": "291, Street 3, Sector I-9/3, Industrial Area Islamabad,",
    "phone_no": "+92-300-8546658"
}
```

Below is the class:

```
public class software_info {
    @SerializedName("sw_name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("sw_address")
    private String address;

    @SerializedName("sw_locations")
    private String location;

    @SerializedName("phone_no")
    private String phNo;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return query ="Name : " + name +
                "Address : " + address +
                "Location : " + location +
                "Phone No : " + phNo;
    }
}
```

Here is the segment of code:

```
JSONObject single = (JSONObject) responc.get(1);        
Gson gson = new Gson();
software_info info;
info = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(single), software_info.class);
// Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), info.query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
dataJson.setText(info.query);
```

Comment: simply print `info` since you have already overriden `toString` method. remove `query=` from `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you get the String as the response. Use this string to get Java Object.

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
software_info info= gson.fromJson(responc.get(1), software_info.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here below I have provided solution:

Parsing method :

```
 public void parseJsonWithGson() {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
            @Override
            public Date deserialize(JsonElement json,
                                    java.lang.reflect.Type arg1, JsonDeserializationContext arg2)
                    throws JsonParseException {
                return new Date(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsLong());
            }
        });
        Gson gson = builder.create();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("sw_name","Comcept (Pvt) Ltd");
            jsonObject.put("sw_id",2);
            jsonObject.put("sw_locations","Islamabad");
            jsonObject.put("sw_address","291, Street 3, Sector I-9/3, Industrial Area Islamabad");
            jsonObject.put("phone_no","+92-300-8546658");
            UserVO userVO = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), UserVO.class);
            System.out.println("-----printing name------" + userVO.getName());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

UserVO class to store data :

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class UserVO {
    @SerializedName("sw_name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("sw_id")
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("sw_locations")
    private String locations;
    @SerializedName("sw_address")
    private String address;
    @SerializedName("phone_no")
    private String phone;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }

    public void setLocations(String locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

How to call this method :

```
 parseJsonWithGson();
```

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried as below and able to get the object -

**Example.java**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {
    @SerializedName("sw_name")
    @Expose
    private String swName;
    @SerializedName("sw_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer swId;
    @SerializedName("sw_locations")
    @Expose
    private String swLocations;
    @SerializedName("sw_address")
    @Expose
    private String swAddress;
    @SerializedName("phone_no")
    @Expose
    private String phoneNo;
    public String getSwName() {
        return swName;
    }
    public void setSwName(String swName) {
        this.swName = swName;
    }
    public Integer getSwId() {
        return swId;
    }
    public void setSwId(Integer swId) {
        this.swId = swId;
    }
    public String getSwLocations() {
        return swLocations;
    }
    public void setSwLocations(String swLocations) {
        this.swLocations = swLocations;
    }
    public String getSwAddress() {
        return swAddress;
    }
    public void setSwAddress(String swAddress) {
        this.swAddress = swAddress;
    }
    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }
    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Example [swName=" + swName + ", swId=" + swId
                + ", swLocations=" + swLocations + ", swAddress=" + swAddress
                + ", phoneNo=" + phoneNo + "]";
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.testgson.beans.Example;

public class Main {
    private static Gson gson;

    static {
        gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "{\"sw_name\":\"Comcept (Pvt) Ltd\",\"sw_id\":2,\"sw_locations\":\"Islamabad\",\"sw_address\":\"291, Street 3, Sector I-9/3, Industrial Area Islamabad,\",\"phone_no\":\"+92-300-8546658\"}";
        Example info = gson.fromJson(s, Example.class);
        System.out.println(info);
   }
}
```

Result -

```
Example [swName=Comcept (Pvt) Ltd, swId=2, swLocations=Islamabad, swAddress=291, Street 3, Sector I-9/3, Industrial Area Islamabad,, phoneNo=+92-300-8546658]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding `single` refers to the JsonObject that you are trying to parse(as you have mentioned), the code should go like this:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
JSONObject single = (JSONObject) responc.get(1); 
software_info info = gson.fromJson(single, software_info.class);
dataJson.setText(info.toString());
```

The fromJson method also accepts JsonElement(JsonObject in this case) as the first parameter, so you can directly pass `single` as the first parameter.
Also, the overridden method toString() in software_info should look like this :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
return "Name : " + name +
       "Address : " + address +
       "Location : " + location +
       "Phone No : " + phNo;
}
```

There is no need to maintain another member variable `query` in your class.